# For a puzzler such as you, you shall solve with ease

Tags: cipher, story, steganography

Your pet cricket has disappeared, due to its undying loyalty and steadfastness you assume foul play must be afoot! After looking around for any signs of confrontation, you find none, but thankfully your years of training it in typing appear to have paid off.

Going to your computer there is a minimized text document that says:

> Good sir. Me exit abruptly, be back. Assuming accurate education, the table will hold put there. Worry not, prompt arrival likely. Like my family I am wont to evacuating uniquely. So bye.
>
> P.S. I am sure we will be reacquainted with ease.

As you read it you are most perplexed by your cricket's lack of prosaicness, dearth of wit and gross misuse of the word uniquely. As such you look in greater detail and find that something has befallen your pet cricket.

What happened to your cricket?

Hint 1:

> I feel like someone else would be more incentivized to give hints than me.

Hint 2:

> Your cricket had always made fun of your puzzle solving skills.

Comment: He appears to have been abducted by a Nigerian Prince.

Comment: What happened to your cricket? Your cricket was given to Mulan for good luck by the grandmother.

Comment: Lol, that looks like something put through Google Translator

Comment: @MarkPeters Just spit out my drink.

Comment: Welp that feeling when the comment has more points than the question...

Comment: These hints are more cryptic than the original puzzle

Comment: Not criticizing; you have me intrigued.

Comment: Ooh, got it! Give me a minute to type it up...

Comment: So...do those hints have anything to do with finding the solution?

Comment: @DanRussell The idea for the first is: The cricket would give you a hint. For the second it points out that maybe the cricket does not think it would be an easy puzzle for you, as such...

Comment: @Goinghamateur That's how I read them. Just not sure how that would help anyone solve the puzzle. Neither one has anything to do with the method of attaining the answer, do they? It sounds like the first one means "check puzzle for hints" and the second means "it's a hard puzzle."

Comment: @DanRussell actually it was why was he saying I am sure you would save it with ease if he is a bad puzzle solver? It is pointing out that ease doesn't mean ease. I will agree the first hint adds fairly little.

Comment: I see, so just trying to point more clearly to the hint that the cricket had already left.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "P.S." hints that

> the letter E is important ("reacquanted with *ease*").

To use that hint, we must

> divide up the text at every E:
>
>  `Good sir. Me`
>  `e`
>  `xit abruptly, be`
>  `back. Assuming accurate`
>  `e`
>  `ducation, the`
>  `table`
>  `will hold put the`
>  `re.`
>  `Worry not, prompt arrival like`
>  `ly. Like`
>  `my family I am wont to e`
>  `vacuating unique`
>  `ly. So bye`
>
>  Counting the letters in each section gives us 9,1,13,20,1,11,5,14,2,25,6,18,15,7. Translating those letters (A=1, B=2...) gives:
>
> **I AM TAKEN BY FROG**

Comment: Nice. I knew that E must have something to do with it, but didn't hit on this approach.

Comment: My hero! -The cricket

Comment: @Deusovi, nice.